# EventHandler listener

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I'm in a position where I have two classes, one has an event handler for a button and I need to be able to listen to that event handler in the other class in order to make changes in the non-button class. I don't have much experience with this type of scenario so am not quite sure where to start.

Comment: Could you describe the problem a bit more.  What is this other class, how is it created, what is its relationship to the page?

Comment: There is a difference between an "event handler" and an "event". Can you clarify your question. It sounds like you mean "event" rather than "event handler".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exampple of this two classes (if I understood the question right).

```
class Form
{
    Button _button1, _button2;

    public Form()
    {
        _button1 = new Button("button1");
        _button2 = new Button("button2");

        _button1.Click += _button_Click;
        _button2.Click += _button_Click;
    }

    void _button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Console.WriteLine(button.Name);
    }

    public void Click1()
    {
        _button1.FireEvent();
    }

    public void Click2()
    {
        _button2.FireEvent();
    }
}

class Button
{
    public event EventHandler Click;
    public string Name;

    public Button(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void FireEvent()
    {
        Click(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    Form f = new Form();

    f.Click1();
    f.Click2();
```

Comment: This is an ASP app, not a winform app.